# Проверка типа данных в переменной

Tags: delphi

Как проверить что в переменной типа string содержатся только цифры и запятые.

Answer (score 2):

Есть функция:

```
function StrToFloatDef(const S: string; const Default: Extended): Extended;
```

На вход она получает строку и число которое вернет в том случае если не сможет в строке распознать число.

Это не совсем проверка. Но, в определенной ситуации может помочь.

Второй вариант - это в цикле перебирать каждый символ строки и проверять его возможную принадлежность числовому значению.

**UPD:**

Также есть функция `TextToFloat()`. Она возвращает результат получилось или не получилось, а распознанное число передает через var-параметр. Собственно `StrToFloatDef()` - это обертка над `TextToFloat()`.

Answer (score 2):

Конвертируете функцией [`val`](http://programmersclub.ru/val/) и смотрите на результат выполнения, если 0, ошибок нет. Вещественное число можно записывать в виде мантиссы и порядка.
Посмотреть еще на `StrToInt`, `StrToDouble`.

Comment: `Val()` - тоже вариант, не знал, спасибо.

А вот `StrToInt()` и `StrToDouble()` вызовут исключение, которое нужно экранировать. Дополнительные строки ненужного кода.

Comment: Да, похоже с `StrToDouble` я перепутал, это в C++. `Val` еще с `Pascal`'я сохранилась.

Answer (score 0):

В поздних версиях Delphi (XE) добавлена поддержка регулярных выражений.

```
Function IsNumericOrSymbol(const checkMe : string) : Boolean;
var
    regex   : TRegEx;
    match     : TMatch;
begin    
    regex := TRegEx.Create('[0-9\,]+');
    Result := regex.IsMatch(checkMe);
    FreeAndNil(regex);
end;
```

P.S. Не проверялось.